# como saber si mi objeto esta vacio en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, blade

estoy haciendo una validacion y necesito saber si el email que busco en mi base de datos existe o no, probe con empty pero no me funciona.

```
$correo = session('userEmail');//coreo que esta llegando de la sesion

            $aux = DB::table('users')->select('email')->where('email', '=', $correo)->get();
            echo $aux;
            foreach($aux as $individual){
                $validacion =  $individual->email;
                echo $validacion;
                if ($validacion == $correo){
                    echo 'bingo';
                }elseif(empty($aux)){
                    echo ' se ejecuta el else';
                    DB::table('users')->insert(
                        [
                            'name' => session('userName'),
                            'email' => session('userEmail'),
                        ]);
                }
            }
```

cuando imprimo el $aux en la linea 4 me devuelve esto [] asi que entiendo que esta vacio.
y por eso pregunto en el elseif si esta vacio que se ejecute mi insercion de datos, pero tampoco se ejecuta, como lo puedo resolver?

Comment: Puede haber muchos usuarios con el mismo email o porqué el foreach?

Comment: no, el foreach por que cuando hago la consulta para buscar el correo me devuelve todo pero en un objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo más directo ahí sería [determinar si no existen registros](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist) con el método `doesntExist()` que te devolverá un `boolean`.

```
if (DB::table('users')->where('email', $correo)->doesntExist()) {
    // insertar datos...
}
```

No es necesario traer ningún registro si no lo vas a usar para nada más.

Comment: lo voy a probar, gracias amigo

Comment: gracias, me funciono a la perfeccion.